# pushing variables to array returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

SOLVED, Thank you! I needed to specify the index.

I am trying to push a set of variables into an array from user input.
Without using push it is working fine;

```
var inputStart = addAppointment.inputStart.value;
var inputEnd = addAppointment.inputEnd.value;
var appointmentArr = [];
appointmentArr = {start:inputStart, end:inputEnd};
document.write(appointmentArr.start);
document.write(appointmentArr.end);
```

however, when I try to push the variables it returns undefined;

```
var inputStart = addAppointment.inputStart.value;
var inputEnd = addAppointment.inputEnd.value;
var appointmentArr = [];
appointmentArr.push({start:inputStart, end:inputEnd});
document.write(appointmentArr.start);
document.write(appointmentArr.end);
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?
As far as I am aware I need to use push because I eventually want to create a new, populated index number every time the user inputs data, so any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing array.
So, the document.write part should be like this

```
document.write(appointmentArr[0].start);
document.write(appointmentArr[0].end);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `appointmentArr` is an array, you should fisrt take `appointmentArr[0]` to access the first `element` of the `array`.

After you push the value, the `appointmentArr` becomes, `[{start:inputStart, end:inputEnd}]`

Since, it is an `array` you **cannot access object keys directly**, you have to take **`specific index element`** and then can access them using `appointmentArr[index]`

```js
    var inputStart = 'inputStart';
    var inputEnd = 'inputEnd';
    var appointmentArr = [];
    appointmentArr.push({start:inputStart, end:inputEnd});
    document.write(appointmentArr[0].start + ' ');
    document.write(appointmentArr[0].end);
```

**Please run the above snippet**

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

You re-assigned your variable as Object.

```
var appointmentArr = [];
appointmentArr = {start:inputStart, end:inputEnd};
```

This code overwrite `appointmentArr` from `Array []` to `Object { start:inputStart, end:inputEnd }`

And in the second code:

```
var appointmentArr = [];
appointmentArr.push({start:inputStart, end:inputEnd});
```

You modify `appointmentArr` from `Array []` to `Array [ {start:inputStart, end:inputEnd} ]`.

So, following code will work as you want.

```
document.write(appointmentArr[0].start);
document.write(appointmentArr[0].end);
```